# service variable undefined at the time of being accessed in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, q

I am trying to implement a controller which has its scope variable being set by service variable like this :

```
$scope.sidebar= resourceService.sidebar;
```

The variable sidebar is set by a function called on startup:

```
var cb = function (api, data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        var logoArray = data[key];
        service.sidebar[key] = logoArray.map(function (logo) {
            logo.img = api + "/" + logo.img;
            return logo;
        });
    }
}
service.requestOnStartup = function (api) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get(config.ApiEndpoint.Base + api).success(function (data) {
        if (angular.isObject(data)) {
            defer.resolve(cb(api, data));
        } else {
            $log.error("[ResourceService] Unexpected data from resource backend");
            defer.reject(data);
        }
    }).error(function (msg) {
        $log.error("Invalid request");
        defer.reject(msg);
    });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

While the control reaches the scope, the service variable is still not resolved and by the time it is resolved, the control over scope is lost. How do i tackle this problem using promises ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine if you are displaying `$scope.sidebar` directly. The variable will be filled asynchronously so it will come after a moment.

If you are doing some action on it while the controller is loading, you'll need to use `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('sidebar', function() {
  if ($scope.sidebar) {...} // check for existence here
});
```

---

By the way, you can simplify your `requestOnStartup` like this

```
service.requestOnStartup = function (api) {
    return $http.get(config.ApiEndpoint.Base + api).then(function (data) {
        if (angular.isObject(data)) {
            return cb(api, data);
        } else {
            $log.error("[ResourceService] Unexpected data from resource backend");
            return $q.reject(data);
        }
    }, function (msg) {
        $log.error("Invalid request");
        return $q.reject(msg);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the existing $q service of angular js:

```
service.requestOnStartup = function (api) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
            $http.get(config.ApiEndpoint.Base + api).then(function (data) {
              if (angular.isObject(data)) {
                resolve(cb(api, data));
              } else {
                $log.error("[ResourceService] Unexpected data from resource backend");
                reject(data);
              }
            }, function (msg) {
                $log.error("Invalid request");
                reject(msg);
            });

    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, I did try it.